# using `tidyeval` with the exposition pipe operator

Tags: r, magrittr, tidyeval

I can't seem to figure out how to use the `%$%` operator from `magrittr` with `tidyeval`. Here is a minimally reproducible example of this problem:

## `table` works with exposition operator outside `tidyeval`

```r
library(magrittr)

print(mtcars %$% table(am))
#> am
#>  0  1 
#> 19 13
```

## `table` doesn't work with exposition operator with `tidyeval`

```r
foo <- function(data, x) {
  # works with pipe operator
  print(data %>% dplyr::pull({{ x }}))

  # doesn't with exposition operator
  data %$% table({{ x }})
}

foo(mtcars, am)
#>  [1] 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
#> Error in table({: object 'am' not found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dplyr::pull` uses tidy evaluation for its arguments. `table` (being a base R function) doesn’t. *That’s* why tidy evaluation works with the former but not the latter. This is unrelated to the pipe operator.